# using Amazon RDS DB with pages in godaddy

Tags: mysql

Currently I have my application running on go daddy but I want to change  my database to AMAZON RDS, I am just wondering if that iss possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you shouldn't. The latency between GoDaddy and Amazon will likely be enough to drastically impact your site's performance.

If you're going to use RDS, you should host in EC2.